# Is it possible to cause a fetch's text() function to throw?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Using the fetch API in modern browsers (or a [node polyfill](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch)), is it possible to generate a scenario in which calling text() on the Response's body could throw?

For the unfamiliar, calling fetch returns a Promise. That promise can then be operated on in sequential then() callbacks. Generally, one will convert the Response's body to either JSON or plain text using the .json() or .text() functions, respectively.

The json() function can throw simply by returning something that cannot be parsed as JSON. Doing so will cause .json() to throw in the same way that JSON.parse() does. However, I've been unable to find a scenario in which .text() can throw.

My cursory examination of the Fetch Spec didn't reveal a way to cause it to throw, though it also didn't mention that .json() could throw either.

Here's some example code that would illustrate the scenario:

```
const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
};

fetch('/my-api-endpoint/', options)
    .then((response) => {
        // Assume we get here and fetch didn't fail before this point
        return response.text();
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        // How do we get here? Is it possible?
        console.log('text() threw');
        console.log(e);
    }).then((text) => {
        // We don't want to get here.
        console.log(text);
    });
```

Resources

- [.text() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text)
- [Fetch Spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/)

Things that haven't worked:

- Sending back JSON as an object specifically - text() converts it to `'[object Object]'`
- Sending back JSON normally - text() returns the JSON string as a string (same as with invalid JSON or non-JSON strings)
- Sending back null or undefined - text() returns empty string
- Constructing a Response artificially and specifying the body value to be null or undefined - text() returns empty string

Comment: Maybe `.text()` cannot throw but `fetch('/my-api-endpoint/', options)` can and you're assuming in your catch that only `.text` throws. You put the catch after 2 promises: `fetch(...)` and `response.text()`

Comment: @HMR Thanks for responding. Yep, fetch can throw. That's why I put the comment "Assume we get here and fetch didn't fail before this point". If we get to that point, then we know that fetch didn't throw. My codebase accounts for the fact that fetch can throw already, but this was a question about the text() function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to cause a fetch's text() function to throw?

<del>It's not possible because `text` runs a [replacement mode decoder](https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#replacement-decoder); furthermore you cannot switch the [error mode](https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#error-mode) of the decoder to `fatal`.</del>

<del>[yutakahirano](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/commits?author=yutakahirano) confirms it in [this comment](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/452#issuecomment-72635225).</del>

`text` may throw

- if its request is aborted between the completion and the consumption
- if the Content-Encoding response header doesn't match the corresponding entity-body

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: @Dwight - In case you weren't notified (I don't think SO does), Knu reversed their answer above a few months later.

Comment: Can you add a citation for the updated answer?

Comment: It's already in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49786130/revisions). Additionally, I had to cover these cases while working on [cb-fetch](https://github.com/Mouvedia/cb-fetch).